# Unable to terraform import s3 bucket state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-import

I prepared a terraform script to provision some s3 buckets as below:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_buckets" {
  count = length(var.bucket_config)
  bucket = "${var.bucket_config[count.index].name}-${terraform.workspace}"
  tags = {...}
}
```

The script works fine when I deploy to dev environment. However, some of buckets have already been manually created in production environment hence the script fails during deployment.

I tried to use `terraform import` to sync the state:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-prod
```

and I received error:

```
aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets: Importing from ID "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-prod"...
aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets: Import prepared!
  Prepared aws_s3_bucket for import
aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-prod]
╷
│ Error: reading Amazon S3 (Simple Storage) Bucket (arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-prod): InvalidARNError: invalid ARN
│ caused by: invalid Amazon s3 ARN, unknown resource type, arn:aws:s3:::bucket1-prod
│ 
│ 
╵
```

I have double triple confirmed the ARN is a valid ARN (I copy/pasted), so wonder what I'm doing wrong here? I did try to double/single quote the ARN too.

Folloiwing @Marcin's answer below, I tried

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets[0] bucket1-prod
```

It indeed solved the ARN issue but failed me with error:

```
no matches found: aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets[0]
```

When I exam my plan, I found output entries like below:

```
  # aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets[0] will be created
  + resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_buckets" { ... }
```

Note the resource is addressed as `"aws_s3_bucket" "my_buckets"` instead of `"aws_s3_bucket" "my_buckets[0]"`. It's probably why I can't use `[0]` in my import statement. Am I doing something wrong with the `count` looping?

P.S. I did validate that `[0]` is the correct index based on the comments in the plan output.

When I run the following command, it works but only for one bucket.

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets bucket1-prod
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify **instance** index which you are importing as you are using `count` and also use a bucket **name**, e.g.

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets[0] bucket1-prod
```

Comment: Thank you, @Marcin. The `bucket1-prod` indeed solve the ARN issue. However, `[0]` is causing me error `no matches found: aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets[0]`. I added some more findings in the question if you could help with!

Comment: @Lee You have to use correct index that matches the bucket. It may be not `[0]`. Only you can verify that.

Comment: I did validate that `[0]` is the correct index.

Comment: Is the bucket in the same account? Maybe tf can't find it if not. I don't know what can be causing the new issue.

Comment: I have only 1 account. It works without `[0]`. In my plan output, it has the following lines. `# aws_s3_bucket.my_buckets[0] will be created`
  `+ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_buckets" { ... }`

Comment: @Marcin, how do you locate the index?